# Contrapositive/contradiction proofs and why do they work

Tags: proof-explanation

Show that if x and y are two integers whose product is even, then at least one of the two
must be even (use the contrapositive argument)

now the thing is I understand how to prove this with a contrapositive argument and without. what I don't get is why proving it with a contrapositive argument works.
The prove would be that
assume x an y are both odd. you do some calculations and get that xy is odd. I don't understand how this proves the other 2 possibilities.  Whats to say that xy isn't ALWAYS odd and we just walked into this nicely. I can only see one way to properly prove this and this is to go through every single (3) case and work it out.  I get that contrapositive arguments are meant to take the idea that x-> q so not x -> not q
but i don't see why cant BOTH results be "wrong"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P\implies Q$ has a contraposition $\neg Q\implies\neg P$.

We can use a simpler proposition to make understanding why easier.

We know that all squares are rectangles.  This can be rewritten as "if this shape is a square, then this shape is a rectangle".  The contraposition is "if this shape is not a rectangle, then **there is no way** that this shape is a square".

Now we draw a shape.  Using geometry, we identify that this shape is not a rectangle.  Therefore, **there is no way** that this shape is a square.

Now we draw a second shape.  Using geometry, we identify that this shape is a rectangle.  Therefore, there is *a possibility* that this shape is a square (but we do not care, nor do we know).

---

Going back to your statement, if $xy$ is always odd, since your statement does not have anything to do with $xy$ being odd, you have no conclusion.  You simply do not care.  You only care that **if** you have $xy$ is even.